# Correct Server Schema to upload pictures in Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to upload pictures to the AWS s3 through the iPhone. Every user should be able to upload pictures but they must remain private for each one of them.

My question is very simple. Since I have no real experience with servers I was wondering which of the following two approaches is better.

1) Use some kind of token vending machine system to grant the user access to the AWS s3 database to upload directly.

2) Send the picture to the EC2 Servlet and have the virtual server place it on the S3 storage.

Edit: I would also need to retrieve, should i do it directly or through the servlet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey personally I don't think it's a good idea to use token vending machine to directly upload the data via the iPhone, because it's much harder to control the access privileges, etc. If you have a chance use ec2 and servlet, but that will add costs to your solution.

Also when dealing with S3 you need to take in consideration that some files are not available right after you save them. Look at this [answer from S3 FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ).

For retrieving data directly from S3 you will need to deal with the privileges issue again. Check the [access model](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html) for S3, but again it's probably easier to manage the access for non public files via the servlet. The good news is that there is no data transfer charge for data transferred between EC2 and S3 within the same region.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that too. How would you suggest I should handle authentication within my servlet? Is there any special api for this? (I am using EC2 to make the java servlet)

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you with that, because I don't know exactly what is your final goal. Mostly depends on how you will store the username and files ownership in your application (rdbms/nosql). Although, AWS is a great product I always try to minimize using specific API, because then it's easier to deploy your app somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Another important point to consider the latter solution

High performance in handling load and network speeds within amazon ecosystem. With direct uploads the client would have to handle complex asynchronous operations of multipart uploads etc instead of focusing on the presentation and rendering of the image.

The servlet hosted on EC2 would be way more powerful than what you can do on your phone.